# After removing parent elements cant get again them

Tags: jquery, parent

Guys i have a button and texarea and when i click it , an 'input button' and 'text i wrote' show up.
After that when i click 'input button' to remove parent elements(that text and input) it works.Everything is normal now.
But when i click button again to get 'input button' and 'text i wrote' showed up again, it is not working.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u95djdqr/4/)

```js
$(function(){

$('#add').click(function(){
  var myWritting = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
  $('#content').html( myWritting +'<input type="submit" value="delete" id="hide"/>')
});

  $('body').on('click', '#hide', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<textarea  id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the element that contains your text and input and not just the text and input itself.
The parent element is needed to be populated by the text and input.

---

So you want to have multiple sets of buttons and text that can be removed by their respective buttons, then wrap them in an element so they can be grouped and removed easily.

```js
$(function(){

$('#add').click(function(){
  var myWritting = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
  $('#content').append( '<p>' + myWritting +'<input type="submit" value="delete" class="hide"/></p>')
});

  $('body').on('click', '.hide', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<textarea  id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Yea that works.Thx! But what if i use 'append' instead of 'html' ?It doesnt work when i use 'append'.

Comment: Do you mean on this line `$('#content').html( myWritting +'<input type="submit" value="delete" id="hide"/>')` ? If so it makes no difference.

Comment: Makes difference man.Use append and add 2 writtings.Then click button to remove only one , both are removed ?

Comment: Okay, so you want to have multiple buttons which only remove themselves and their associated text. For that you should wrap them in an element to group them. This will make them easier to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the `content` div. Instead, you need to remove the children elements of the `content` div.

```
$('body').on('click', '#hide', function() {
    $(this).parent().children().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Only button removed ?

Comment: You changed your fiddle.. You aren't inserting a `<p>` tag so it won't get deleted. You can do `$(this).parent().html('');` though. It's fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/em1hjko9/1/